# How to give space between paragraph elements with display:contents ("unusual element")?

Tags: html, css

I'm given paragraphs such as these below.

```
<p class="sr-only">Eren Marie, passed away on Friday, April 23, 2019.</p>
<p class="sr-only">She was born on March 23, 1987 to Jeffrey and Susan. Erin is survived by her loving husband, Peter Stevens, and daughter, Rose Irene; father Jeffrey and mother Susan; brother Seanand sisters Lauren</p>
```

To force my site to display the paragraphs, my CSS is this.

```
.sr-only {
    display: contents;
}
```

But the repercussion is that all the paragraphs have no spacing in between them. They just look **like one long paragraph**.

I tried `margin-bottom`, `padding-bottom` and nothing works. I can't remove the `sr-only` class cos it's in thousands of profiles as of now.

How do I create the space in between?

Comment: Why not just remove that CSS? It's what's causing the paragraphs to run together.

Comment: There're thousands of profiles with that class. So, I wish to just use CSS to fix this, if possible.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can try this approach.

```js
$( "<br><br>" ).insertAfter( ".sr-only" );
```

```css
.sr-only {
    display:contents;
    
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.0.js"></script>
<p class="sr-only">Eren Marie, passed away on Friday, April 23, 2019.</p>
<p class="sr-only">She was born on March 23, 1987 to Jeffrey and Susan Staton. Erin is survived by her loving husband, Peter Stevens, and daughter, Rose Irene Stevens; father Jeffrey Staton and mother Susan Staton; brother Sean Staton and sisters Lauren Staton</p>
```

Comment: I wish I could use <br>. There are thousands of profiles on the site. So, I was hoping to fix it by just using CSS instead of having to fix all the elements in ALL the content.

Comment: ok. maybe line-height will work on your end look at the edited code

Comment: line-height would increase the height for each line, wouldn't it? That's not what I need, I need to put a space in between paragraphs. Anyway I tried but it didn't work.

Comment: my bad i still have the br. ok let me edit it.

Comment: You can do it by putting script.  This is the best way I can think of so far.

Comment: @codanad376 someone already provided a CSS only and working solution

Comment: @TemaniAfif . codana is forcing her code to use display:contents so hopefully if she change it to display block will work as well. I'm just trying to help on the best way and easiest way. Thanks for the neagtive on it

Answer (score 0):

You can use CSS to add a [pseudo-element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::after) in between each paragraph. If you then set the display of this to block you can add whatever padding you wish.

```
.sr-only::after {
  content: " ";
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
}
```